# can talent be gained or is it inbuilt in us from birth?

Tags: fundamental-entities

i want to know, can any talent be gained if u have interest in that particular thing.
As said : "U can succeed in life, if u have talent and if it is used well".
Is there any person borne with talent already in him or a new talent is just born in him because of his motivated hard work towards that subject.
So at last my question is , can any talent be born in us if we work hard and motivated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That all depends on which definition of the word [talent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/talent) you are using:

1. a special natural ability or aptitude (e.g. *a talent for drawing*)
2. a capacity for achievement or success (e.g. *young men of talent*)

The first definition is specifically a measurement of natural, inborn ability.  Education and effort may reveal a previously unrealized natural talent, you cannot create inborn talent where it does not exist.

However, the second definition is dependent on results, and results are certainly impacted by hard work and motivation.  As the saying goes, "[Hard work beats talent when talent doesn’t work hard.](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-procrastination-equation/201110/hard-work-beats-talent-only-if-talent-doesn-t-work-hard)"